# Minimal polynomial of generating Galois automorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, galois-theory

Let $K/k$ be a finite cyclic Galois extension with Galois group generated by $\sigma$. Now forget about the $k$-algebra structure and interpret $\sigma$ as an endomorphism of the underlying $k$-vector space of $K$. Is it true, that the minimal polynomial of $\sigma$ is $X^n-1$? Why? Why couldn't there be a linear combination to zero of powers of $\sigma$ less then $n$?

Comment: Is it true that $x^n-1$ is the characteristic polynomial of $\sigma$?

Comment: Actually, in every cyclic group of order $n>1$, a generator $g$ satisfies $g^n=1$ and $g^k≠1$ if $1<k<n$ (in particular this is true for the cyclic group $\langle \sigma \rangle$).

Comment: @watson yes, but this alone does not tell you something about linear combinations.

Comment: Yes, my comment was only about the first question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupid me: This is just linear independence of characters.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I'm quite curious.

Comment: I think I see. The functions $\chi(x=\sigma^k)$ for $0\leq k < n$ are linearly independant over $k$ (By virtue of the $\sigma^i$ being distinct) and thus so are the $\sigma^i$ by duality? So $\sigma^n=1$ is really the smallest degree relation we could have? Very neat.

Comment: @Jake: Apply independence of characters to $\sigma^i\colon k^\times\longrightarrow k^\times$ for the different homomorphisms $\sigma^i$, $i=0,\dots,n-1$.